# SAS log not including code

Tags: logging, sas

I'm facing the following situation. The sas log since some days is not more including the original code, BUT only

- green commentary
- red commmentary

Before, the log was working as expected, including the code too.

I have checked on the web but being unable to find a solution.

**Question :** There is some option/code which is able to restore the option to have the code too included in the log?

***Update:*** As per Richard, the first option didn't solve the issue. Below the log for the two option you suggested:

```
  NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR

  SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M3


Group=LOGCONTROL
 CPUID             Prints the CPU identification number at the beginning of the SAS log.

 DATE              Prints the date and time that a SAS program started.
 DECIMALCONV=COMPATIBLE
                   Specifies the binary to decimal conversion and formatting methodology.

 NODETAILS         Does not display additional information when files are listed in a SAS library.

 DMSLOGSIZE=99999  Specifies the maximum number of rows that the SAS Log window can display.

 NODTRESET         SAS does not update the date and time in the titles of the SAS log and procedure output file.

 NOECHOAUTO        Does not write statements that are in the AUTOEXEC file to the SAS log as they are executed.

 ERRORS=20         Specifies the maximum number of observations for which SAS issues complete error messages.

 HOSTINFOLONG      Print operating environment information in the SAS log when SAS starts.

 LINESIZE=132      Specifies the line size for the SAS log and for SAS procedure output for the LISTING destination.

 LOGAPPLNAME=      Specifies a SAS session name for SAS logging.

 NOLOGLANGCHG      Disables changing the language of the SAS output when the LOCALE= option is changed.

 LOGPARM=WRITE=BUFFERED ROLLOVER=NONE OPEN=REPLACE
                   Specifies when SAS log files are opened, closed, and according to the LOG= system option, how they are named.

 MISSING=.         Specifies the character to print for missing numeric values.

 MLOGIC            Traces macro execution and writes the results to the SAS log.

 NOMLOGICNEST      Does not display the macro nesting information in the SAS log for MLOGIC output.

 NOMPRINT          Does not display the SAS statements that are generated by macro execution.

 MSGLEVEL=N        Specifies the level of detail in SAS log messages.

 NEWS=!SASROOT/misc/base/news
                   Specifies the location of the news file that is to be written to the SAS log immediately after the header.

 NOTES             SAS writes notes to the SAS log.

 NUMBER            Prints the page number on the first title line of each page of SAS output.

 NOOVP             Disables overprinting of error messages to make them bold.
 NOPAGEBREAKINITIAL
                   Does not begin SAS log and procedure output for the LISTING destination on a new page.

 PAGESIZE=60       Specifies the number of lines that compose a page of the SAS log and SAS output.

 PRINTMSGLIST      Specifies to print the entire list of messages to the SAS log.

 NOSOURCE          Does not write program source statements to the SAS log.
 SOURCE2           Writes secondary source statements from included files to the SAS log.

 NOSYMBOLGEN       Does not display the results of resolving macro variable references in the SAS log.
 ECHO=             Specifies a message that is echoed to the SAS log while initializing SAS.

 RTRACE=NONE       Specifies whether to produce a list of resources that are read or loaded during a SAS session.

 NOFULLSTIMER      Does not write performance statistics to the SAS log.
 NOMSGCASE         Specifies that SAS writes notes, warning, and error messages in mixed casing.

 NOOPLIST          Does not write SAS system option settings to the SAS log.

 STIMEFMT=(NLDATM2. HMS TIMEAMPM KB MEMFULL TSFULL NC)
                   Specifies the format that is used to display the FULLSTIMER and STIMER output for timestamp, memory, CPU and 
                   elapsed time statistics.
 STIMER            Writes real and CPU time to the SAS log.

 NOVERBOSE         Does not write start-up system options to the SAS log.

NOTE: PROCEDURE OPTIONS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds



    SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M3


Group=LOG_LISTCONTROL
2                                                          The SAS System                            18:23 Tuesday, February 6, 2018

 DATE              Prints the date and time that a SAS program started.
 DECIMALCONV=COMPATIBLE
                   Specifies the binary to decimal conversion and formatting methodology.

 NODETAILS         Does not display additional information when files are listed in a SAS library.

 NODTRESET         SAS does not update the date and time in the titles of the SAS log and procedure output file.

 LINESIZE=132      Specifies the line size for the SAS log and for SAS procedure output for the LISTING destination.

 NOLOGLANGCHG      Disables changing the language of the SAS output when the LOCALE= option is changed.


 MISSING=.         Specifies the character to print for missing numeric values.

 NUMBER            Prints the page number on the first title line of each page of SAS output.

 NOPAGEBREAKINITIAL
                   Does not begin SAS log and procedure output for the LISTING destination on a new page.

 PAGESIZE=60       Specifies the number of lines that compose a page of the SAS log and SAS output.

NOTE: PROCEDURE OPTIONS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: How are you connecting to SAS?  SAS Enterprise Guide?  SAS/Studio? SAS Display Manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking or setting the SOURCE option

```
options SOURCE;
```

If that does not appear to fix the problem, update the question with the log shown after submitting this code:

```
proc options group=logcontrol;
run;

proc options group=log_listcontrol;
run;
```

Comment: nice use of `proc options` groups

Comment: Hi Richard. I was wrong, as I was using source2 option instead that source. As I changed to source it seems the situation is back to normal. Many thanks for the precious input.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for showing (generated) SAS code is `options mprint;` - as per [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000209298.htm), this will show the code generated by SAS macros (if any).

Whilst it won't show code, `options notes;` gives a more verbose log, and - whilst on by default - is sometimes switched off for performance reasons.